Audio visualizer: What can I improve in this circuit?
Being a beginner in electronics, I embarked on designing and building a sound visualizer, turning bass, mid, and high frequencies into red, green, and blue light in an RGB LED strip.
I designed the circuit on CircuitLab and the simulations went well; I implemented the circuit on breadboards, and sending a test signal from 20Hz to 20kHz nicely turns the strip from red to green to blue.
What I'd like to request from the community is some pointers on rookie mistakes in my design, anything that shows a lack of fundamental best practices. Just because the circuit works doesn't mean it works the best it can, but I have no other resources to have someone with expertise look over my work.
The signal comes from an iPad headphone jack. The filters come from the Texas Instruments filter design tool. I am planning to look into a better amplifier design and play with that next. 

It is also possible to do the filtering in software. The 32 Bit Arduino modules allow to use FFT transformation to support even more frequency bands. A TL071 cannot directly drive a speaker. Consider a microphone amp as input, this is useful for a party context with different sound sources.

@Jens I'm good at math and coding (wrote FFT on the Arduino from scratch for practice); electronics is the new hobby I'd like to get better at. Thanks for the tip on driving the speaker!

You don't need OA2, 3 and 5. OA1 can drive the three filters if you use a larger value for C1 (> 10 uF) or use a DC connection.

@Jens, would "direct connection" be a clearer way to describe the DC connection?

Yes, the input OpAmp and the filters operate symmetrically around GND, no need for a capacitor between them. Offset errors are eliminated behind the filters. Just another hint: OpAmp output voltages can be anything during power up, even including the supply rails. So you must protect the arduino inputs in some way. Series resistors and clamping diodes are a common solution.

@SimonFitch  There is a note under the far-left block that reads: "All op-amps receive +/- 15 V".

@FabioBarone yes, there is, didn't see that, thanks

@SimonFitch  no worries, cheers.

Here are some suggestions for improvement, refer diagram below for key.




OA2 & OA5 are not needed.  The filter bank can be fed from the one op-amp, OA3.

Need to put protection for the inputs of the Arduino, ie: voltage clamp.  Series R with clamp diodes to the 0V & 5V supply of the Arduino.  Select series R to limit the current to something like 1mA under worst-case conditions.  Refer figure 2 below.

The op-amp will struggle to drive an 8Ω load.  Options are:
3A.  Insert a buffer stage (unity gain but with good current drive capability), or
3B.  Replace the speaker with an output jack to drive a high-impedance headphone, or the input of an external amplifier-spearker combo.

Put pull-down resistors at the gate of each MOSFET (gate to source).  10kΩ should be fine.  Insert a buffer stage (unity gain NPN/PNP pair) between the Arduino output and the MOSFET gate, in case the MOSFETs require more current drive than what the Arduino can safely supply.  Put plenty of power supply by-pass capacitors here, refer figure 4 below.

Put current limiting resistors between the LEDs and the MOSFET drains.  This is in case the MOSFETs get stuck on, you don't want to blow either the +12V supply, the LEDs, or the MOSFETs.



Figure 2, Voltage Clamp

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Figure 4, Gate Drive Buffer

simulate this circuit

Thank you for this substantial answer. As I suspected, most of my design flaws are located at the junction points between the components. I am going to put a designated audio amplifier to drive the speaker - which I really only need because the headphone jack shuts off the device speaker, and I want to hear what I am visualizing. I really appreciate learning about the "protective gear"!!

OK, happy to help.  You may want to consider increasing the value of C1, to extend the low-frequency response.  It may be worth putting similar voltage clamps where the signals move from one block to another, eg: between the signal source and the summing amplifier at the front end, and between the buffer amplifier and the LP, BP, and HP filter bank.  Power supply rails going up and down at random as power is turned on and off has caused many damaged circuits, so would be wise to consider how your power supply works.  Cheers.
